# Compare 2 lists and create new list from differences

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a database table with Person objects. My web service receives a list of Person objects to update this Person table. My application now contains 2 lists:

```
List<Person> current;
List<Person> updated;
```

I want to iterate through these lists and create a new list that I will use to update the Person table.

```
Person {
   String fName;
   String lName;
   String age;       
   String email;
}
```

fName and lName are used to identify existing records. The following is an example.

Current:

| fName | lName | age | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Bloggs | 18 | joe@me.com |
| Jane | Bloggs | 21 | jane@me.com |
| Flo | Bloggs | 25 | flo@me.com |

New:

| fName | lName | age | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Bloggs | 18 | joe_bloggs@me.com |
| Jane | Bloggs | 21 | jane@me.com |
| Flo | Bloggs | 90 | flo@me.com |

Records to update database with:

| fName | lName | age | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Bloggs | 18 | joe_bloggs@me.com |
| Flo | Bloggs | 90 | flo@me.com |

Comment: *"I want to iterate through these lists and create a new list"* Then I suggest you write some code to do exactly that. You do know how to iterate a list, don't you? And how to compare values using `if` statements?

Comment: @Andreas I am - I haven't added the edit yet. I saved it prematurely.

Comment: Then delete it and re-create when ready.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward solution would be to ensure `Person` has its [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) & [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) defined such that it compares the objects based on these fields.  Then, you can create a list containing all the `updated` objects, then remove any elements that exactly equal an element in `current`.  The resulting list will be just the elements that have changed.

```java
public List<Person> changedPersons(List<Person> current, List<Person> updated) {
    List<Person> changed = new ArrayList<>(updated);
    changed.removeAll(current);
    return changed;
}
```

```java
public class Person {
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String age;
    String email;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(fName, lName, age, email);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        return Objects.equals(fName, other.fName)
                && Objects.equals(lName, other.lName)
                && Objects.equals(age, other.age)
                && Objects.equals(email, other.email);
    }
}
```

---

If you cannot define `equals`/`hashCode` on `Person` in this manner, you could create wrapper object that has this desired equivalence relation, convert the objects to this, perform the same algorithm, then convert back at the end.

```java
public List<Person> changedPersons(List<Person> current, List<Person> updated) {
    List<PersonEquivalence> changed = updated.stream()
            .map(PersonEquivalence::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    changed.removeAll(current.stream()
            .map(PersonEquivalence::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList()));
    return changed.stream()
            .map(PersonEquivalence::getPerson)
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
}

private static class PersonEquivalence {
    private final Person person;
    public PersonEquivalence(Person person) { this.person = person; }
    public Person getPerson() { return person; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(person.fName, person.lName, person.age, person.email);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof PersonEquivalence)) {
            return false;
        }
        PersonEquivalence other = (PersonEquivalence) obj;
        return Objects.equals(person.fName, other.person.fName)
                && Objects.equals(person.lName, other.person.lName)
                && Objects.equals(person.age, other.person.age)
                && Objects.equals(person.email, other.person.email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to find all items of a list that are not in another list.

I suggest you define your objects as records so that you can easily compare them.

```
record Person(String fName, String lName, String age, String email) { }
```

Finding the updated records is then a simple matter of:

```
var difference = updated.stream().filter(p -> !current.contains(p)).toList();
```

Comment: The big downside of this approach is that records won't be in a long term support version of Java until Java 17 releases this September.  Using a non-LTS version of Java has risks that might not be acceptable in a corporate environment.

Comment: @M.Justin there was no mention of corporate environments in OP's question or any restrictions on Java version. It makes no sense to restrict SO answers to LTS features as this is a key way in which newer features enter common use.

Comment: I'm not arguing against this being an answer, nor am I arguing for restricting SO answers to LTS features.  What I am arguing for is calling out the downsides and risks involved when it's highly likely they're relevant.  Much Java development happens in an environment (corporate or otherwise) where it is worth considering whether using a non-LTS version of the language should occur.  Given that, it's something that the OP and future visitors should be aware of, though it may or may not be a concern in their particular use case.

Comment: I see your point but we'll need to agree to disagree on this one. SO answers are available for many years beyond the relevance of of the status of new features. Personally I'd prefer to see answers that use the latest features of a language and leave it to the reader to determine if they are appropriate for their particular case. Note that record are no longer in preview so they are a permanent feature of the language.